# Is there a clojure IDE can help autocomplete Java object method?

Tags: java, emacs, intellij-idea, clojure, cursive

Is there a clojure IDE that can help autocomplete a Java object method?

For example:

```
(def my-temp-file (java.io.File/createTempFile "filename" ".txt"))
```

then i want to input:

```
(.deleteOnExit my-temp-file)
```

how can i :

(. my-temp-file delet|"cursor here") ;; how can i get auto-complate del* methods

or

(.delet|"cursor here" my-temp-file) ;; how can i get auto-complate del* methods

...

just now, I tried intellij14.1.4 + cursive0.1.60, it's wonderful.

i tried to  auto-complate from "delete" to " deleteOnExist"

Situation 1 ,This is ok:
[image: Situation 1 ,This is ok:]

Situation 2 ,this canot work :
[image: Situation 2 ,this canot work :]

How can I get the "deleteOnExist" autocomplete in Situation 2? please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your example is that `def` does not automatically add the `:tag` metadata based on the type of its initialiser. You can see this as follows:

```
Connecting to local IDE...
Clojure 1.7.0
(import java.io.File)
=> java.io.File
(def temp-file (File/createTempFile "filename" ".txt"))
=> #'user/temp-file
temp-file
=> #object[java.io.File 0x6c8b97fd "/var/folders/x1/9k18lcbn4qnfs4pptm0dm8fm0000gn/T/filename8344242261832815384.txt"]
(meta #'temp-file)
=> {:line 1, :column 1, :file "NO_SOURCE_PATH", :name temp-file, :ns #object[clojure.lang.Namespace 0x548b68c5 "user"]}
```

So your example will work in cases like the following:

```
(let [temp-file (File/createTempFile "filename" ".txt")]
  (temp-file .dele|))
```

Where `|` represents the caret. It will also work if you manually add the tag to your `def`, like:

```
(def ^File temp-file (File/createTempFile "filename" ".txt"))
```

Answer (score 7):

[Cursive Clojure](https://cursiveclojure.com), an IntelliJ plugin has excellent Java interop that can do this for you.

Comment: How can I get the "deleteOnExist" autocomplete in Situation 2? please help

Comment: Situation 2 doesn't look like valid Clojure interop to me? I think it should be `(.deleteOnExit my-temp-file)`. And I don't think Situation 1 will actually work either?

Comment: They're not valid interop, but Cursive uses those forms for interop completion. Using postfix rather than prefix means that you have the type of the target object (since you typed it first) so Cursive can offer totally accurate completion. When the method name is completed, Cursive will swap it with the target object so it becomes valid.

Answer (score 1):

Since you put the tag emacs, you can try `cider` with `ac-cider`. However, I found this combo a bit error-prone in terms of auto-completion precision. The suggested options can be methods from other classes.